# Passing a string to a stored procedure from Python produces an error

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, stored-procedures

I don't understand why I get the following results. My SQLServer 2017 MSSC looks like:

[image]

Why am I getting: NameError: name 'pr' is not defined?

Charles

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
DECLARE @my_script nvarchar(100)
```

This isn't long enough and your python gets truncated to the following

```
foo = "Hello " + "world"
print("foo1: ", foo)

foo = "" + "world"
print("foo2: ", foo)

pr
```

You should increase `nvarchar(100)` to a higher amount.